# Prove Sequence Diverges

Tags: calculus

The sequence is $a_n=(-2)^n$

I know it diverges to $-\infty$ and $\infty$ depending on even and odd powers, but I have no clue how to start and using what method. I could use contradiction but the same proof for something like $\sin(x)$ I don't think we can use here. Would I be doing $M-N$ proofs and showing both cases diverge or is there an easier way?

Comment: Write down the definition of converge. Negate it. That should be a good first step. Recall that diverge=not converge. Don't worry about diverge to infinity or anything like that.

Comment: I'll give it a shot thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you have suggested contradiction, a simple route could be to show that the sequence is not bounded.

This assumes of course that you have previously shown that any convergent sequence is bounded.
If this is not the case, it would be a good exercise to prove it as a lemma.

Answer (score 2):

Every convergence sequence is bounded.  The sequence $a_n$ is not bounded so it is not convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Show the sequence diverges by showing that it does not converge; that is, as $n \to \infty$, $a_{n} = (-2)^{n}$ does not get arbitrarily close to some finite number $L$.

In this case, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \neq L$ for any real number $L$; and hence, does not converge.

Therefore, the sequence $a_{n} = (-2)^{n}$ diverges.